# How to install GMP on CentOS?

Tags: shell

I tried to install GMP on CentOS but I could not.

The output message is:

```
[root@localhost fedora]# wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz
--2015-06-04 01:43:53--  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz
Resolving ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)... 208.118.235.20, 2001:4830:134:3::b
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)|208.118.235.20|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1904112 (1.8M) [application/x-xz]
gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz: No space left on device

Cannot write to ‘gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz’ (Success).
[root@localhost fedora]#
```

What *Cannot write to ‘gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz’ (Success)*?

Comment: May be you do not have free space, you can check for example with `df`.

Answer (score 2):

The filesystem holding the `/tmp` directory is full (100%). This usually triggers the reflex of checking free space with `df` as wisely suggested by [taliezin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207470/how-gmp-install#comment350276_207470). If the temporary folder belongs to the root file system you *have* to remove unneeded files [from the root filesystem] while you can.

Answer (score 1):

The "Success" message is odd, but the important one is `gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz: No space left on device`: you need to find a filesystem with enough room to store the tarball.